# Django JWT token not working properly with my react app

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, next.js

When I have SessionAuthentication it's working but the same code didn't work when enabling jwt token-based authentication.

Take a look at my working code when  SessionAuthentication:

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    .... others 
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    'drf_spectacular',
    'corsheaders',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
   
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
       
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),

    'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'drf_spectacular.openapi.AutoSchema',  
    
}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    "ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(minutes=5),
    "REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(days=1),
    
}
```

**API endpoint code**

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def get_user_profile(request):
    print(request.headers)
    if request.user.is_anonymous:
        return Response({'error': 'User is not authenticated.'}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
    
    user = request.user
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
    data = {
        'username': user.username,
        'account_point': profile.account_point,
        'mobile_number': profile.mobile_number,
        'city': profile.city,
        'country': profile.country,
        'address': profile.address,
        'is_verified_email': profile.is_verified_email,
        'is_verified_mobile_number': profile.is_verified_mobile_number,
    }
    return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**my react code:**

```
 let headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',

      };
    axios.get(`${CustomDomain}/user_profile/`,{withCredentials:true,headers: headers})
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
```

When added JWTAuthentication in my api code then it's not working.

**my not working code:**

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@authentication_classes([JWTAuthentication]) #not working when added
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated]) 
def get_user_profile(request):
    .... others code
```

error which I am getting in my frontend

```
{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}
```

I also added few screenshot here from my network tab
[image]

[image]